# exiv2 UserComment metatag

Tags: metadata, exiv2

What is the difference between the following statements for setting a comment string

```
exiv2 -c tera img.JPG
exiv2 -M"set Exif.Photo.UserComment adagio" img.JPG
```

I can access them with

```
$ exiv2 -p c img.JPG
tera
$ exiv2 -p S img.JPG | grep adagio
         450 | 0x9286 UserComment                  | UNDEFINED |       14 |     38546 | ........adagio
```

What would be the proper way to add simple ASCII characters that won't longer than a dozen of characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command saves the text to the jpeg COM block (see [Jpeg Syntax and structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Syntax_and_structure)).  This is a jpeg only piece of metadata.

The second command saves the text to the EXIF `UserComment` tag.  This is part of the [EXIF standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exif) of metadata.

The jpeg COM comment is a fairly fragile place to put metadata, as some programs will either not save it or overwrite it with their own text.  The `UserComment` is less likely to be lost or overwritten by most programs.

Comment: As a side note, can you add own metatag with `exiv2 -M"add Exif.Photo.myTag value" img.JPG`? But it seems not possible, then what would be the difference between `add` and `set` when modifying metadata?

Comment: You can't just make up your own tag like that.  The various standards (EXIF, IPTC/IIM, XMP) are defined in very specific ways.  While it is possible to add to them, you have to define where they go in order not to overwrite tags that already exist. I don't know if it's possible with exiv2, but [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org) has options to create your own tags, but it's very complex (see the [`example.config` file](https://exiftool.org/config.html)).  As to the difference between set and add, I don't use exiv2, so I can't help there.